# How does かたじけなや differ from regular かたじけない?

Tags: nuances, archaic-language

Many times I heard/read an archaic form of giving thanks to somebody かたじけない modified to かたじけなや. I also think I heard ありがたや quite a lot.

What exactly does this や at the end (is it regional, emphatic, or else?) and how does it sound to a native speakers' ears?

Comment: Not quite "emphatic" but kinda close.  Think of another word starting with an 'e'.  That was too much of  a hint.

Comment: I would appreciate some more examples of Japanese expressions using this particular や if they existed...

Comment: 他には「おそろしや」「うらめしや」とか・・・？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This や is an old 終助詞 which is [described here](http://www.asahi-net.or.jp/~sg2h-ymst/yamatouta/intro/josi05.html#ab02). It's probably similar to the English exclamation mark, or "Oh/O" seen in verses and lyrics. Basically it is only found in old Japanese and haiku. (や used in Kansai-ben is different from this, I think)

In *modern* Japanese usage, ありがたや sounds archaic as compared to ありがたい. It sounds as if you were jokingly simulating a person in the past who is faithfully worshiping Japanese 神 and 仏. Or it sounds like you were thanking for something in an exaggerated manner, as if you saw a miracle of God.

A typical usage of ありがたや can be found in [this page introducing a VPN router](http://jp.yamaha.com/products/network/solution/asciimw_bb_03/). The men in the picture are worshiping the almighty router!

> QoSも、VPNも、バックアップも1台で済むとは。ありがたや、ありがたや

Don't use it in formal situations, because ありがたや is usually used jokingly like this.

I think かたじけない is already an archaic, samurai-like wording, and people use it only as a joke today. So I see very little difference between かたじけなや and かたじけない. Theoretically though, the former is more emphatic.